# Why Spark JDBC infers table schema even when schema is specified?

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, spark-jdbc

I'm using `spark.read.format("jdbc").option("query", tmpSql)` to load a table from Mysql, and I can see a query `select * from (xxx) where 1=0` from database monitor, later I know this query is used for inferring table schema in Spark.
However when I use `spark.read.format("jdbc").option("query", tmpSql).schema(xxx)`, the table schema inferring query is still there.
Why Spark still need to infer table schema when customSchema is already specified?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `customSchema` parameter of spark jdbc.

```
.option("customSchema", schema_str)
```

Comment: It's the same as `.schema(xxx)`